# How to Remove (class="local-link">) from our website internal links

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to know how to remove this line:

`class="local-link">`

which is appear just before our all internal links.

I have found this code on our website Source Page.

```
class="local-link">
```

Comment: man you need to study how HTML is rendering..

Comment: unclear what you're asking: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question

Answer (score 0):

if you want just to remove the attribute class from an element like `div` use jquery, for example if you have this `<div class="local-link"></div>`

and with jquery do `$('.local-link').removeAttr('class');`

EDIT:

If you want to remove `local-link` and let the attribute class empty you should do this: `$('.local-link').removeClass('local-link');`

Comment: I want to remove the whole `class="local-link">` and want to leave it blank. So Tell me How to do this.

Comment: You want to remove the attribute class or jst the value `local-link`?

Comment: want to remove the attribute class

Comment: like I said in my answer you need to use jquery, $('.local-link').removeAttr('class');`

Comment: Sorry for Not explaining... I want to remove attribute class & value local-link both. I would like if you tell me where i add the above code in my wordpress theme.

Answer (score -1):

Download all the files by ftp. Search them for the string 'local-link'.

Please give reason why not leave it there.